# RestEASY + Jboss 7.x - can you default to first @Path when Accepts doesn't match @Produces value?

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I have the following web service in RestEASY 3.6.2 on JBoss 7.1.0.

```
@GET
@Path("/getstuff")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "," + MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getStuff() {
```

I send a request with the following: `Accept` = `application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`

http://localhost:8080/myapp/getstuff

returns:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>Internal Server Error</body>

</html>
```

When I specify `Accept` = `application/json` it returns the correct response.

Is there some "default fallback" I can use to make Resteasy use the first matching Path instead of failing?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error.  There must be something else in your code. Please provide more information in your question and [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

`Hello`, 
`Accept header` is used by HTTP clients specify for the server what content types will be accepted. The server will then send back a response, which will include a Content-Type header specifying to the client the kind of content actually is.

This is relevant because the requests might be POST or PUT requests. 
This would explain the issue, therefore, cause the content type is conflicting with the Json.

Comment: Sorry this is not correct. Thanks for responding though.